# RtcUtility.h: No such file or directory

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, rtc

I have a problem with remaining headers. Can't seem to find the first header "RtcUtility.h". Anyone how to fix? I've provided a picture for you to see.

[image: Sample picture]

Error Messages:

> Arduino: 1.8.10 (Windows 7), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4M (no SPIFFS), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"
>
> sample_time:6:24: error: RtcUtility.h: No such file or directory
>
> Multiple libraries were found for "ArduinoOTA.h"
>    #include
>
> Used: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2\libraries\ArduinoOTA
>                           ^
>
> Multiple libraries were found for "Wire.h"
>   compilation terminated.
>
> Used: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2\libraries\Wire
>   Multiple libraries were found for "ESP8266WiFi.h"
>    Used: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi
>   Multiple libraries were found for "ESP8266mDNS.h"
>    Used: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2\libraries\ESP8266mDNS
>   exit status 1
>   RtcUtility.h: No such file or directory
>
> This report would have more information with
>   "Show verbose output during compilation"
>   option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the RTC library in the Arduino as below.

*Open the Library Manager and search for "Rtc by Makuna" and install.*

You can also checkout the Github page for that particular library at

https://github.com/Makuna/Rtc